# How can I access parameter inside @() in MVC view using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
function getdescription(MYPARAM) {
  @(Warehousing.EnumHelper.GetEnumDescription(EnumModelClass).Convert.ToInt32(MYPARAM));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this code is being executed where Razor/Blazor is interpreted (ie. *not* in a .js file), then the value will be output to the source. As such you can just place JS syntax around it to work with the value on the client side. Try this:

```
function getdescription(MYPARAM) {
  let myValue = @(Warehousing.EnumHelper.GetEnumDescription(EnumModelClass).Convert.ToInt32(MYPARAM));
  console.log(myValue);
}
```

Comment: i am getting MYPARAM but when i use it inside Convert.Toint(MYPARAM) , it is not working

Comment: Can you give more information than 'it isn't working'? What happens? I presume an error, is it a JS error, or a C# one? What is the value in `MYPARAM`? Is it a valid Int32?

Comment: hi @Rory McCrossan , the line inside @() is my problem , I am not able to access MYPARAm inside @() code.

Comment: i think c# one but i am not sure , may be there is an alternative for problem in javascript .

Comment: it is about code inside  @(here)   .Do you know how to access my parameter inside @(here..)?

Comment: The code above will work, assuming C# provides a valid value.. If you're asking how to access the `Warehousing.EnumHelper.GetEnumDescription(EnumModelClass)` value, then no one can answer that here without a more descriptive explanation of your system. That problem also seems irrelevant to JS.

Comment: i think same .anyway thanks for your precious time.

Comment: No problem, hopefully it was of some benefit to you

Comment: @JordiJordi unlikely as the OP is converting the value to an `Int32`.